# How to convert information in a row to columns in notepad++ or excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, notepad++

I have the following information:

67.141.139.122  93.26.180.87  67.182.16.216

I want the output as:

67.141.139.122
93.26.180.87
67.182.16.216

Comment: Try to use Text to Column option and then cut and post to Transpose.

Answer (score 2):

It is rather easier in Notepad++ than in Excel.
In Notepad++...

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to open the Replace dialog box
2. In the **Find What** box enter a space (You can verify it if you
   select the text in the box)
3. In **Replace With** box enter `\r\n` for *Windows* file format (or just `\n` for *Unix* files or just `\r` for *Mac* format files)
4. Make sure to select **Extended** as the Search Mode. (It interprets
   the character after the **\** as special character - in this case: a newline
   character)
5. Press **Replace All** ( In general, for more complex replacements,
   do a **Replace** first which replaces one instance of the character to
   check if its working properly and then **Replace All** once you have
   figured out that it works)

[Check the screen shot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtAxy.png)

Answer (score 0):

replace spaces whit new lines any editor can do !